# Filter notifications that should warn is possible?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an app that receive two types of notifications from my webserver (with APNS): **Important Notifications** and **Normal Notifications**.

The main difference between these two types of notifications is that `Important Notifications` should appear in the notifications bar on device (when the app is on background mode) and `normal notification` not.

`Normal Notifications` is only for update some information inside my app and it is not necessary to warn users when the app is in background mode. knowing that, this kind of thing is possible?

Comment: You could use Silent Push Notification for the normal ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your backend service has to send the non-important push notification with

```
{"content-available":1}
```

in its payload dictionary. Then the user won't see the push notification on the home screen.

Comment: And don't forget to delete `'alert' : 'new notification'` and `'sound' : ' '` to take effect